# How to install SQLite on Windows?

Tags: database, windows, sqlite, installation, precompiled-binaries

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html - The download page shows 3 pre-compiled zips for the database. It doesn't look like a full installation. Where am I supposed to install these files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the list:

> Precompiled Binaries For Windows
>
> sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3070701.zip
>   (244.12 KiB)        A command-line shell for accessing and modifying SQLite databases.
>
> sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3070701.zip
>   (278.28 KiB)        This ZIP archive contains a DLL for the SQLite library version 3.7.7.1.
>
> sqlite-analyzer-win32-x86-3070701.zip
>   (710.48 KiB)        An analysis program for database files compatible with all SQLite versions through 3.7.7.1 and beyond.

There are **shell** and **analyzer** program that can be used to interactively work with sqlite databases without writing any code. *Shell* is an interactive SQL command-line interface; and *analyzer* is program to get info about some sqlite database. You can place this tools anywhere, or install them to some folder, which is in your %PATH%.

**DLL** is compiled sqlite library that should be placed in your application directory.

Answer (score 4):

You can install SQLite on Windows so that you can use it on terminal(command prompt).

First, download the 3rd one saying `A bundle of command-line ...` from [the website](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html):

[image]

Then, unzip it, then get 3 files below, then put them in `C:\sqlite\` which you need to create manually:

```
sqldiff.exe
sqlite3.exe
sqlite3_analyzer.exe
```

Then, search and click on `Edit the system environment variables`:

[image]

Then, click on `Environment Variables...`:

[image]

Finally, set `C:\sqlite` to **Path** in both or either **User variables** and/or **System variables**, then you can use SQLite on terminal(command prompt). ***User variables** are specific only to the currently logged-in user and **System variables** are globally accessed by all users:

[image]

Comment: better answer imo